# Hbase regions splitting when they shouldn't be

Tags: hadoop, hbase

We have some tables configured with DelimitedKeyPrefixRegionSplitPolicy (inherits from IncreasingToUpperBoundRegionSplitPolicy), a memstore flush size of 128M and a table MAX_FILESIZE of ~20GB.

Based on our calculations we shouldn't get more than 5 regions per server until the region sizes reach 20GB (4^3*256M = 16GB) but we have 7-15 regions per region server.

We had previously combined them to get the correct number but then they just split again. We are using hbase 0.98.4 and table description shows {TABLE_ATTRIBUTES => {MAX_FILESIZE => '21474836480'... The default region max filesize is 1 GB and many of the regions are larger than that.

We can't figure out why they keep splitting despite our best efforts to keep to region count smaller. Any ideas?

Comment: We tried changing the max_filesize to 100GB as shown here https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/util/RegionSplitter.html and we are still getting splits

Answer (score 1):

You should change the split policy

```
METADATA => {'SPLIT_POLICY' => 'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.ConstantSizeRegionSplitPolicy'}
```

Comment: If we did that we would have to set the max size extremely high and manually manage splits because we need them to split on prefix boundaries. We could fall back to that, but what we are doing now is supposed to work according to the docs and I don't understand why it doesn't.